# Trouble writing to streams with sockets

Tags: c

I'm quite new to C and am having trouble with writing to streams using sockets.

I'm using a network stream/socket to try to send messages in two directions (from host to client and client to host) however when I get the message back from the client it's scrambled (due to an encoding issue I guess?).

Here's the relevant parts of my code:

**host.c**

```
int client_sock_fd;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    while (1) {
        char input[80];
        scanf("%s", input);
        // send to client, transmitted fine
        write(client_sock_fd, &input, sizeof(input));             

        char response[80];
        read(client_sock_fd, &response, sizeof(response));
        // Prints the missing character symbol, and 'random' letters
        printf("Response: %s\n", response);
    }
}
```

**client.c**

```
int host_sock_fd; // file descriptor for host

void writeResponse(

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    while (1) {
        char message[80];
        // the message is transmitted fine
        read(host_sock_fd, &message, sizeof(message));

        writeResponse("Response message");
    }
}

void writeResponse(char response[80]) {
    write(host_sock_fd, &response, sizeof(response));
}
```

I'm not really sure how to continue. I know if I simply write back the received message in client it works fine, so is this a problem with the amount of memory for each char?

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I've learned a lot from your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I showed a lack of knowledge below, and I'm not going to delete it, but this is what causeing your problem in `writeResponse(char response[80])` since `response` is treated as `char *` and not `char[80]`. But in general, don't use the `&` when it is not needed, it causes mistakes just as the one you had. treat `char[]` as `char *` where it is about the level of referencing, there are differences between those two, but not in this case.

<strike>It's weird that it works at all, since you declared your buffers as `char input[80];` etc., those variables are already char pointers and you should not pass their address as parameter to the read /write functions so it should be:</strike>

```
write(client_sock_fd, input, sizeof(input));
```

instead of:

```
write(client_sock_fd, &input, sizeof(input));
```

in all cases of read write. You may want to take a look at [those](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/academic/class/15213-f99/www/class26/tcpserver.c) [examples](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/academic/class/15213-f99/www/class26/tcpclient.c)

Comment: No, they are `char` **arrays**. `&` on a char array returns the same as the char array.

Comment: To clarify: `input` is an array and response (in `writeResponse`) is an address.

Comment: +1 "in general, don't use the & when it is not needed" my feelings exactly ;)

Answer (score 2):

First of all I can see you are ignoring the return code of **[`write(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write)** and **[`read(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read)**. Be aware that there is not guarantee related to the number of octets *actually* sent / received when using these calls.

> If a function be advertised to return
>   an error code in the event of
>   difficulties, thou shalt check for
>   that code, yea, even though the checks
>   triple the size of thy code and
>   produce aches in thy typing fingers,
>   for if thou thinkest ``it cannot
>   happen to me'', the gods shall surely
>   punish thee for thy arrogance.

You should check the `size_t` returned and keep reading until `EOF` (return 0 says `read(2)`).

Comment: @MByD: actually you were right. In that context (`writeResponse`) `response` is actually a pointer (the `[80]` is ignored by the compiler). **Sorry** for not reading carefully.

Comment: Thanks for this, I've added error checking on my read and write calls, and altered client's while loop to read until bytes_read returns 0 - I'll update the code to show this.  However I'm still getting random characters through?

Comment: @Ross That is because part of the answer (probably most of the answer) is what @ChrisWue suggested: get rid of `&` in `writeResponse` (or you'll be sending some random 4 bytes).

Answer (score 1):

Apart from MByDs answer you are also passing a string of 17 characters (inluding \0) to the `writeResponse` function and then claiming it is actually <strike>80</strike> 4.

Better:

```
void writeResponse(const char* response) {
    write(host_sock_fd, response, strlen(response) + 1);
}
```

**Update**: Fell into the array trap as well. Note that

```
void foo(char *bar)
```

and

```
void foo(char bar[80])
```

are equivalent and `sizeof(bar)` will return the size of a char pointer in both cases.

Comment: Thanks, I've obviously got quite a bit to learn with this. \0 is the null string terminator right?

Comment: Yes, \0 is the null terminator. Also `strlen` doesn't count it, therefor the +1